Why do Pinned Start Menu items periodically disappear?
Every few months, all my pinned Start Menu items in my Windows 10 setup disappear, and are replaced with a "Productivity" group. I mean this literally: every 2-3 months, over a period of maybe 5 years.
It is sending me up the wall.
For info, none of the stock cut-and-paste textbook responses typically seen on the Microsoft Forums will serve any purpose here:

The resource checker found no "integrity violations"
The deployment tool said the operation completed successfully, but didn't tell me what the operation was. The machine wasn't "deployed"; it was hand installed from media, so I don't know if I'd expect it to yield anything useful.
The directory %LocalAppData%\Packages\Microsoft.Windows.StartMenuExperienceHost_cw5n1h2txyewy\LocalState does not contain the expected start.bin file.
The directory %AppData%\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Quick Launch\User Pinned does not contain the expected StartMenu folder.

I've used variations of Windows over the last 35 years from around Windows 3.1, and I know a few tricks myself, but this one has me baffled.

What could create the Productivity folder?
Why are my start menu pinned items not stored at the normal place?
Is there something in the registry which is causing them to be stored elsewhere?

Anyone who might have an idea, your help would be greatly appreciated.


Nor mine. just this one machine.

I did say that the deployment tool said the operation completed successfully (utterly useless response). However your suggestion yields "The operation could not be completed due to pending operations." That's new.
